# Mesh intersection detection

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm doing an procedural building generator that using room prefabs. Everything is fine when generation depth less than 5-6. But when the depth is deep enough, the rooms begin to intersect.

There's main generator method:

```cs
private void GenerateRoom(int depth, int maxDepth, Transform parent, int roomIndex, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, int currentRotation)
{
    if (depth >= maxDepth || (!LimitRotation && (Mathf.Abs(currentRotation) > MaxRotation)))
        return;

    int randomRoom = -2;
    do
    {
        int random = Random.Range(0, Rooms.Select(x => x.Priority).Aggregate((a, b) => a + b));
        IEnumerable<RandomRoom> sortedRooms = Rooms.OrderByDescending(x => x.Priority);
        int acc = 0;
        foreach (var r in sortedRooms)
        {
            if (random < r.Priority + acc)
            {
                randomRoom = System.Array.IndexOf(Rooms, r);
                break;
            }
            acc += r.Priority;
        }

        if (randomRoom == -2)
            return;
    }
    while (randomRoom == roomIndex);

    ProceduralRoom room = Instantiate(Rooms[randomRoom].Room, position, rotation, parent);

    foreach (ExitPoint exitPoint in room.ExitPoints)
    {
        GenerateRoom(depth + 1, maxDepth, room.transform, randomRoom, exitPoint.Position, exitPoint.RoomRotation,
            currentRotation + (int)exitPoint.RoomRotation.y);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see where exactly you check for intersections .. but do you really need mesh intersection (quite expensive to process) or is it just based on rectangles ..?